# IS there any sql query to solve this

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a table with three fields start_range, end_range and point
Now the value is given and i to find the right point of the value meaning the value must be greater than the start range and less than the end range, I need the point for that range stored in the DB.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: ok Ill try to explain it: Table has rows start_range, end range and point now suppose i have start_range 10 end range 20 and point 25 and the given value is 15 i need the point 25 to be filtered

Comment: @manjilSthapit This explaining comment should rather be part of the question...

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, read How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table 
where value>start_range and value<end_range
```

Comment: no this doesnt work i have tried this will not return any value is the end_range is exceeded

Comment: @manjilSthapit This seems to match what you requested for/how you described your problem – apart from selecting *all* columns instead of just the `point` one – `value` would have to be replaced with your concrete search value, in your example (in the comments) with 15 – if that's not what you need then you need to specify the question/example more clearly.